# Right way to setup google analytics on a razor page in asp netcore

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, google-analytics

I currently have some forms, 6 in total, built on razor so I want to track how many times each form is sent.

On Google Analytics I created a goal and set it as custom, the category is count, the action is click, the label is houseform and the value is 0.

In my solution for the forms I have the following, the code for the analytics I copy paste in from the dashboard.

I followed or try to followed the Analytics guide but I just cant make it work, on my goals dashboard this goal appears as 0 and I let more than 24h to fetch information just in case it doesn't appear immediately.

Can someone give me an advice on how to make this work, I have to make this exact thing on more forms, so any help is highly appreciated.

**_Layout.cshtml**

This is inside the head tag

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXX-X"></script>
<script>
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag()

            {dataLayer.push(arguments);}

            gtag('js', new Date());

            gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXX-X');
</script>
```

And this is the form tags I'm using

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-row">
        <form method="post" id="razorForm">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label asp-for="HouseQuote.Name" class="control-label">Nombre</label>
                <input asp-for="HouseQuote.Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" />
                <span asp-validation-for="HouseQuote.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label asp-for="HouseQuote.Email" class="control-label">Email</label>
                <input asp-for="HouseQuote.Email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
                <span asp-validation-for="HouseQuote.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label asp-for="HouseQuote.OwnerType">¿Eres?</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" asp-for="HouseQuote.OwnerType">
                    <option value="Propietario">Propietario</option>
                    <option value="Inquilino">Inquilino</option>
                    <option value="Arrendador">Arrendador</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="HouseQuote.OwnerType" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label asp-for="HouseQuote.HouseValue" class="control-label">¿Cuál es el valor de la casa?</label>
                <input asp-for="HouseQuote.HouseValue" class="form-control" placeholder="¿Cuál es el valor de la casa?" type="number" min="0" />
                <span asp-validation-for="HouseQuote.HouseValue" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label asp-for="HouseQuote.HouseContentValue" class="control-label">¿Cuál es el valor de los contenidos?</label>
                <input asp-for="HouseQuote.HouseContentValue" class="form-control" placeholder="¿Cuál es el valor de los contenidos?" type="number" min="0" />
                <span asp-validation-for="HouseQuote.HouseContentValue" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label asp-for="HouseQuote.ZipCode" class="control-label">Código Postal</label>
                <input asp-for="HouseQuote.ZipCode" class="form-control" placeholder="Código Postal" type="number" min="0" />
                <span asp-validation-for="HouseQuote.ZipCode" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px;">
                <label asp-for="HouseQuote.TelephoneNumber" class="control-label">Teléfono</label>
                <input asp-for="HouseQuote.TelephoneNumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Teléfono" type="number" min="0"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="HouseQuote.TelephoneNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-left:15px;">
                <input type="submit" id="submitProcess" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="gtag('event', 'click', {'event_category':'count','event_label':'houseform','value':'0'});" />
            </div>
        </form>
        <div id="load-container">
            <div id="loader" class="loader my-auto text-center"></div>
            <p class="text-center">Por favor espere, estamos enviando su solicitud</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Many browsers stop executing JavaScript as soon as the next page
> starts loading, which means your gtag.js event commands may never run.

> The solution is to intercept the event to stop the next page from
> loading so that you can send the event to Google Analytics. After the
> event has been sent, submit the form programmatically.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/sending-data

```
// Get a reference to the form element, assuming
// it contains the ID attribute "signup-form".
var form = document.getElementById('razorForm');

// Add a listener for the "submit" event.
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {

  // Prevent the browser from submitting the form
  // and thus unloading the current page.
  event.preventDefault();

  // Send the event to Google Analytics and
  // resubmit the form once the hit is done.
  gtag('event', 'signup_form_complete', {
    'event_callback': function() {
      form.submit();
    }
  });
});
```